# How to Force 0 show in excel cell for ROUNDDOWN?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Good day I have the following Excel formula:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(C30/4;0)
```

In `Cell (C30)` is:

```
3
```

In the resulting cell it shows an empty cell.

I would like the cell to show `0`

Note: My `Excel version is 2010`

Comment: The formula should work (assuming the ; is a regional setting).  Have you checked the formatting to see if you have something special set for displaying 0?

Comment: I can't reproduce this either (again, assuming that ";" is regional due to "," being used elsewhere). It might be worth trying to set the Cell Format to number?

Comment: Yes my regional settings use a semicolon. Anyway the excel is a generated sheet, when I write the formula elsewhere on the page it works. In that particular cell where the error occurs, a yellow exclamation mark is displayed along with this message: `this cell contains a formula and is not locked to protect it...`

Answer (score 0):

Since I cant post a comment I'll post an answer. I plugged this into my copy of excel 2010 and it worked fine (general format for the cell). It also worked when I used a special cell with 0 selected. Has your cell format been modified in any way?

Comment: Yes, it has been changed to `numFormat = '#'`, which in terms of excel means integer I think